# Why make a partition at all for mdadm/raid?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, disk-space, software-raid, mdadm

i have 4 disks, sd[a,b,f,g] of various sizes that I want to 'merge' together. I am using mdadm to achieve this.

my question is, what's the difference between --

> mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=linear --raid-devices=4 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdf /dev/sdg

and

> mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=linear --raid-devices=4 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdf1 /dev/sdg1

When both work? For some reason (if someone could explain this too, it would be awesome) I lose a lot of disk space as is when I look at /dev/md0 but if I create partitions and then create a linear raid, I  end up losing even more space.

So  why create partitions at all? Even when I do not have this setup and just want to use a disk, can I just do a mkfs.ext3 /dev/sda ?

---

Additional stuff - 
Here's /proc/partitions -

8        0  244140625 sda 
   8        1  244139008 sda1
   8       16  244140625 sdb
   8       17  244139008 sdb1
   8       80   39063024 sdf
   8       81   39061504 sdf1
   8       96  156290904 sdg
   8       97  156289024 sdg1

WHy are the sizes of my partitions smaller than my disk as listed above?

Comment: It is perfectly legal to do that, but you will have problem if you try to do that on your boot drive.  Your will need to store your boot loader somewhere.

Comment: Note that you're not losing any space until the fifth significant figure. That is, the loss -- which is used for storing the partition table, MBR, and other metadata -- is tiny and not worth worrying about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why make a partition at all

You need partitions if you want to use part of a drive for RAID for a specific array. You can also be more flexible with more partitions.

Example:

```
1 TB HDD #1:    SDA1 (500 MB)     SDA2 (490 MB)
1 TB HDD #2:    SDB1 (500 MB)     SDB2 (490 MB)
1 TB HDD #3:    SDC1 (500 MB)     SDC2 (500 MB)
```

I can add sda1, sdb1 and sdc1 in a stripe for performance,
and sda2 and sdb2 in a mirror for security,
amd sdc2 just as a plain disk.

I can not do that if I use the whole drive.

In your case you seem to want only one single large setup, which means that it does not matter which way you do it.

Comment: All right thanks. Yeah I just want the entire disk (atleast for the disks I have). So this clarifies it :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question, but there is a good reason to use partitions with MDADM, specifically when using a RAID5 or RAID1-configuration (so not in OPs case):

With RAID5, for the rebuilding process to work if a disk fails, the replacement disk has to be the exact same size as the original disk. Since the capacities of hard disks are not exactly the same between manufacturers, you can run into problems when you mix disks made by different manufacturers. This is quite inconvenient. To get around this, you can use partitions instead and leave a small bit of space at the end of each disk (like 100 MB each), so that the partitions can be made to have the exact same size accross all different hard disk models.

A similar thing applies when you use RAID1, because in that case, the mirrored disks need to have the exact same size. Using physical disks instead of partitions can cause problems in this case as well, because, again, sizes between manufacturers are not exactly the same.

For a simple RAID0-configuration, though, there's no real reason to use partitions instead of physical disks, really.

For further reading, see [RAID - Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/RAID#Partition_the_devices)

Comment: In addition, you can name partitions and so improve management.
Partitioning will also protect the data in situations where something could write to the start of the disk, like when the disk is attached to a separate computer or when a different system is booted for testing or inspection.